# how can i solve this dictionary problem?(It's so confusing for me)

Tags: python, dictionary

the code below is an order list containing dictionaries. what i want to do is: to sum the price in dictionaries where the first key:value is the same ("name":"coffee"). Then print a new list with only one of these similar dictionaries with the price summed up. (if possible i want this to be solved in a way where i can use it on an example where i cannot see the inside of list or it's dictionaries--> meaning i don't want to use the keys and values themselves but something like indexes or similar stuff)

`order = [{"name":"coffee", "price":5}, {"name":"mug", "price":10}, {"name":"coffee", "price":6}]`

expected outcome:
`order = [{"name":"coffee", "price":11}, {"name":"mug", "price":10}]`

I tried to use different for loops but i didn't get an output except i got some confusing loop errors.

Comment: Show us your attempt(s) to solve it* and then we can help you get on track.
*Add them to the original question

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sum-list-of-dictionaries-with-same-key/

Comment: @MattClarke sorry this is my first time. ill keep this in mind

Comment: @oskros thank you. i didn't know about this link before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 from collections import defaultdict 
 order= [{"name":"coffee", "price":5}, {"name":"mug", "price":10}, {"name":"coffee", "price":6}]
 my_dict = defaultdict(int)
    
 for d in order:
    my_dict[d['name']] += int(d['price'])#sum the value of each name
 print([{'name': name, 'price': price} for name, price in my_dict.items()])# convert the key-value pair to  a list of dictionaries
```

output:-

```
[{'name':'coffee', 'price':11}, {'name':'mug', 'price':10}]
```

Comment: Mate, you forgot tu insert 'name' _key inside the output list.

Comment: @johnycapo yup my bad!

Comment: thanks a lot. i tested it. it is a nice approach, and it is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Easy Way for you to understand

```
order = [{"name":"coffee", "price":5}, {"name":"mug", "price":10}, 
        {"name":"coffee", "price":6},{"name":"mug", "price":20},{"name":"Glass", 
         "price":20}]

# dict to keep distinct name and their total price
distinct_order={}
total_order=[]
for o in order:
   if o['name'] in distinct_order:
       # if "name" already exists, it will add the price
       distinct_order[o["name"]]+=o['price']
   else:
       distinct_order[o["name"]]=o["price"]

# distinct_order contains name:price and to change format  into list of 
#dictonaries of name and price.  
for i in distinct_order:
    total_order.append(dict(name=i,price=distinct_order[i]))
print(total_order)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'coffee', 'price': 11}, {'name': 'mug', 'price': 30}, {'name': 'Glass', 'price': 20}]
```

If you understand, go for a better appraoch,
this is just basic or naive approach for you to understand as you are getting problems in understanding loops.

Comment: thanks a lot. its fun to learn how things work.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `collections.defaultdict()` can be used to make creation and initialization of new dictionary keys easy. I want to point out that there is also a way to do this without importing `collections` using `setdefault()`. I tend to use it rather than `defaultdict()`.

```py
orders = [
    {"name":"coffee", "price":5},
    {"name":"mug", "price":10}, 
    {"name":"coffee", "price":6},
    {"name":"mug", "price":20},
    {"name":"Glass", "price":20}
]

## ------------------
## Accumulate a dictionary of item totals
## Note:
## setdefault(key, default) works a lot like defaultdict
## it will return the value of the key if it exists and
## if not, it will set the key to the default and return it
## ------------------
orders_totaled = {}
for order in orders:
    name = order["name"]
    price = order["price"]
    orders_totaled[name] = orders_totaled.setdefault(name, 0) + price
## ------------------

print(orders_totaled)
```

This will give you:

```
{'coffee': 11, 'mug': 30, 'Glass': 20}
```

At this point, if you wanted to cast that to a list of dictionaries you can do:

```py
orders_totaled = [{"name": n, "price": p} for n, p in orders_totaled.items()]
print(orders_totaled)
```

Giving you:

```
[{'name': 'coffee', 'price': 11}, {'name': 'mug', 'price': 30}, {'name': 'Glass', 'price': 20}]
```

Comment: thank you . i didn't know about setdefault. its new to me